# How to reduce Passenger + Apache waiting time (TTFB)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, performance, passenger

I have developed application in rails and I am using passenger with apache and it happened a lot that some of the assets went to pending state although they are very small in size like this:

[image]

It went to pending state and it's loaded after 1.5m wait.

[image]

What I should do to improve my apache response time. Here are my passenger settings.

```
PassengerMinInstances 18
PassengerMaxPoolSize 150
PassengerPoolIdleTime 500
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
  StartServers          70
  MinSpareServers       120
  MaxSpareServers       200
  MaxClients            300
  MaxRequestsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Can you please suggest a solution on this?

Comment: I didn't found any solution yet. I have configured cloudflare which could help a little bit